# Customizing Ext.js grid panel's title

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

Is there a way to customize the title of ext.js grid panel (or is there a more generic way of customizing panel title) by adding custom controls to it, and not tool buttons?

I am tring to add a search field to the title, but with current existing implementation (found in the ux/grid example) it is shown how filter can be added to the **drop down menu** of the grid's title, and not to the **title** itself, which is what I am trying to achieve..

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the grid panel's [`header`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-header) config, where you can set any configuration option of [`Ext.panel.Header`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header). As it is a container, you can just specify its [`items`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Header-cfg-items) there:

```
header: {
    title: 'Test',
    titlePosition: 0,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }]
}
```

Also check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/620).

Answer (score 0):

Header is a container with `hbox` layout so you can add/remove items to it as to any other container. You can test it (for example) here: http://extjs.eu/apps/saki-writable-grid/ by typing

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('maingridview')[0].getHeader().add({xtype:'textfield'});
```

in the console. The textfield appears at the header right.

As to grid filtering, see [Grid Search Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-search-plugin/) that can be added also to the grid header.